# Another word for "A relationship of causality/ cause-effect relationship"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, synonyms

I am not sure if "cause-effect relationship" fits in this context. I have looked for better alternatives but I couldn't find one that fits here:

> So far, this chapter has provided an analysis of the dynamics of rape politics ***as far as the cause-effect relationship*** between the enactment of rape policies and the degree of their enforcement is concerned.

Basically, what I want to say is that the importance of enacting a policy/law is determined by the degree of its enforcement—i.e., what is the point of enacting a law if it is not being abided by.

Comment: It's unclear what you're looking for.

Comment: I believe the standard phrasing is something like "*A law without enforcement is just good advice*" (or "*... is not a law*"?), but I can't remember the exact quote.

Comment: "Honored in its breach" is what some hack poet said.  But, that said, most people obey most laws whether they are vigorously enforced or not, because most people are law-abiding people.

Comment: Maybe _correlation_ is the word you're looking for?

Comment: Ah but @barmar, *correlation* is most emphatically not *causation* :)

Comment: the concepts of *only paying lip service* and *checking the block* come to mind.  or maybe even *pencil-whipping*.

Comment: If that's what the chapter says and you're summarizing as such then fine.  But if it's your own conclusion, then you may need to take a step back and look at the bigger picture.  The political climate as determined by the agendas of those holding office as well as public opinion on current events determines both legislation as well as enforcement priorities.

Comment: Does enactment _cause_ enforcement, or does enforcement _cause_ enactment? I think neither is the case, and thus you are not looking for _causality_. I think @Barmar is right, you seem to be looking at the _correlation_, which does _not_ imply a cause-effect relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Some words you could use in place of cause/effect are stimuli, catalyst, and impetus.

However in your case, I'd rephrase the sentence as:

So far, this chapter has provided an analysis of the dynamics of rape politics concerning the link between the enactment of rape policies and their degree of enforcement.